# Changing path to mysql socket in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mysql

I would like to use Mysql in QGIS. But when I want to create a new connection to the database (*Add Vector Layer*), I can't connect because QGIS is looking for

```
/tmp/mysql.sock
```

But I'm using **XAMPP** for Mac OS X so the socket is in

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
```

Is there a way to change the path to the mysql socket in QGIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently solving my problem using a simple:

```
ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I know that's not a clean solution but it's the easier I found.